# Tire marks in sharp turns

Tags: chevrolet, steering, astro

My Chevrolet Astro is leaving tire marks in sharp turns. By looking at the car during the maneuver it is evident that the outer front wheel is angled too strong, i.e. it is "falling over itself" (slightly exaggerated), thus producing the marks. The tire on the ground stems from the outer 20℅ of the tire. Both sides *seem* to be affected equally strong. The problem is not visible in wider turns.

An alignment did not help, the issue persists even after setting the toe-in to 0° for both wheels (manufacturer range: 0° ±0.06'). Both idle arms have been replaced ~1 month ago due to sluggish steering.

**What could cause this effect? Where should I look first?** I can provide more parameters of the alignment report if helpful.

Comment: Does your Astro van have the AWD option? Did the van do this prior to having the "idle arms" replaced?

Comment: How old are the tyres?

Comment: You need to do a thorough check of the ball joints.